# Android : Animation not finishing before starting next activity

Tags: android, animation

I have set animation for an image button. What I expect it to do, is fade out, and then start the next activity.

This is not what is happening.

It is starting the next activity, and then when 'back' is pressed, the animation is still 'running', and finishes the fade out. I tried various combinations of: setting the animation for a longer duration in the XML, putting the animation in a thread, and using a thread to sleep, and putting the animation in the sleep thread... I have not found with winning combination! Still not getting the animation to complete before the next activity is started.

Any help is appreciated!

XML for fade out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<alpha
  android:fromAlpha="1.0"
  android:toAlpha="0.1"
  android:duration="1000"
  />
</set>
```

Code in android: (for the onClick of the imageButton)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Current.this, Next.class);
            v.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
            try {

                Thread.sleep(1200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: Let me get you right, It doesn't work for back button pressed? But if you just click the imagebutton and let it run, it works?

Comment: Nope - it doesn't work when the  image button is pressed, but when the back button is pressed: the fade in shows. In essence, the animation is starting, but doesn't complete before the next activity starts, even when using a thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try using AnimationListener as shown below:

```
animationFadeOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `AnimationListener` described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) and in `onAnimationEnd` start your `Activity`. You can use like this: `animationFadeOut.setAnimationListener(listener)`

Comment: Thank you - I knew there must be some kind of listener!